# How to fetch only the part that uncomment in a config

Tags: linux, grep

I am using the following command to get the working part of any config file that works.

```
grep -v -e '^[[:space:]]*$' -e "#"
```

How accurate is this?
If there are other way like this method  and easy please comment.

Comment: `How accurate is this? `: It depends on your requirements. Please add sample input and expected output to clarify further.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```bash
grep -vE '^(#|[[:space:]]*$)'
```

See the online demo:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
s='# ...

             
take me'
grep -vE '^(#|[[:space:]]*$)' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
take me
```

*Details*:

- `v` - negates the result
- `E` - enables POSIX ERE regex syntax
- `^(#|[[:space:]]*$)` - matches start of string (`^`) and then either a `#` char or (`|`) zero or more whitespaces (`[[:space:]]*`) at the end of string (`$`).